# How to merge two object arrays by adding matching object in as a new field

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have these two arrays:

```
const goodCars = [
    { name: 'ferrari', price: 22000, condition: { isGood: true, isBad: false } },
    { name: 'ford', price: 21000, condition: { isGood: true, isBad: false } },
    { name: 'bmw', price: 20000, condition: { isGood: true, isBad: false } },
  ];

  const badCars = [
    { name: 'ford', price: 1111, condition: { isGood: false, isBad: true } },
    { name: 'honda', price: 8000, condition: { isGood: false, isBad: true } },
  ];
```

My goal is to produce this final array:

```
  const finalCarList = [
    { name: 'ferrari', price: 22000, condition: { isGood: true, isBad: false } },
    {
      name: 'ford',
      price: 21000,
      condition: { isGood: true, isBad: false },
      toCompareWith: { name: 'ford', price: 1111, condition: { isGood: false, isBad: true } },
    },
    { name: 'bmw', price: 20000, condition: { isGood: true, isBad: false } },
    { name: 'honda', price: 8000, condition: { isGood: false, isBad: true } },
  ];
```

Basically I want to merge the two `goodCars` and `badCars` arrays into one but if the cars exists in both good and badd arrays then I want to add the bad car to the good car array as a new field `toCompareWith: {...}` (seen above)

I've tried using `map()`, `reduce()`, `for` loops, etc. but my brain has hit a wall and I'm not getting any closer.

My attempt:

```
 goodCars.map((gc) => {
    badCars.map((bc) => {
      if (isCarMatch(gc, bc)) {
        finalCarList = [
          ...finalCarList,
          { ...gc, toCompareWith: bc },
        ];
      }
    });
 });
```

Answer I went with based on the below marked correct one: ✅

```
  let finalCarList: Array<Car> = [...goodCars];

  badCars?.forEach((bc) => {
    const match: Car | undefined = goodCars.find((gc) => isCarMatch(gc, bc));
    match
      ? (match.toCompareWith = bc) // Slot in matching item
      : (finalCarList = [...finalCarList, bc]);
  });
```

Comment: Please show what you think is your best attempt. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Comment: @Barmar added attempt code.

Comment: What if you have more than one bad car of the same make? Should `toCompareWith` be of type array?

Comment: @PeterKA i'll always have one for my use case. But that a valid point. I've not attempted it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use nested loops.

Start by copying `goodCars` to `finalCarList`. Then loop over `badCars`. If the car is in `goodCars`, add the bad car as the `toCompareWith` property. Otherwise, push it into `finalCarList`.

```
finalCarList = [...goodCars];
badCars.forEach(bc => {
    match = goodCars.find(gc => isCarMatch(gc, bc));
    if (match) {
        match.toCompareWith = bc;
    } else {
        finalCarList.push(bc);
    }
});
```

Also, in general you shouldn't use `map()` if the callback function doesn't return anything. If it's called only for side effects, use `forEach()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Barmar

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example using two [`for...of` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). The outer loop is the first array and the inner loop is the second array using [`.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) in order to track a matches index. If there's a match, the object in the second array is removed and is assigned as the value of `.toCompareWith` property of the matched object of the first array. After the loops are completed, both arrays are merged.

```js
const goodCars = [
    { name: 'ferrari', price: 22000, condition: { isGood: true, isBad: false } },
    { name: 'ford', price: 21000, condition: { isGood: true, isBad: false } },
    { name: 'bmw', price: 20000, condition: { isGood: true, isBad: false } },
  ];

  const badCars = [
    { name: 'ford', price: 1111, condition: { isGood: false, isBad: true } },
    { name: 'honda', price: 8000, condition: { isGood: false, isBad: true } },
  ];
  
const mergeCars = (arrA, arrB) => {
  for (let carA of arrA) {
    for (let [idx, carB] of arrB.entries()) {
      if (carA.name === carB.name && carA.condition.isGood !== carB.condition.isGood) {
        carA.toCompareWith = carB;
        arrB.splice(idx, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  return [...arrA, ...arrB];
};

console.log(mergeCars(goodCars, badCars));
```